# Embeded Power BI IFRAME

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a local database and i published a report, then i create the gateway in the portal and generate the iframe and paste it into my web site... after that i enable the schedule too. Finally I create a new record on the table associated to the report i published and when i went to the portal i didnt watch the new record so i noticied that i have to force the refresh in the power bi portal, but in the iframe that i have in my web site doesnt show the new record. I noticed than after and hour the data is refreshed in the iframe, but is there a way to do this without wait too much.

PD: Sorry about my english.

Comment: No there isn't. There's always a lag on the embedded power bi stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a refresh of the view (report or dashboard) using JS SDK:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding---Basic-interactions#refresh-a-report

This will not refresh the data in your dataset, as Refresh Now does in Power BI, but provided the data is updated already, this will cause the visuals to show the updated data